# SQL Server restart/large database restore impacting stored procedure unexpectedly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan, sqlperformance

My scenario, without getting into the detail... Our nightly operations revolve around restoring a ~700GB 2008 compatibility level database from a SQL Server 2016 machine to SQL Server 2017, let's call this database `NightlyDB`, to support our reporting operations.

Once a month, we perform an additional restore from the same backup file to another database on the same server - `MonthlyDB`. This occurs after `NightlyDB` is restored.

The restored to server is Windows patched/restarted on a monthly basis. After the restart, one of the overnight stored procedures takes noticeably longer that normal (this is in `ReportingDB` (Compatibility Level 2012) pulling from `NightlyDB`). It takes a couple of runs of our overnight operations for events to settle back to normal. The procedure concerned performs a truncate/large insert (~17 million records)/numerous updates. Query store isn't enabled on `ReportingDB` and the time taken to restore is unaffected by the restart, roughly 1 hour.

During the update steps of procedure there are a lot of global update statements that could be rolled into a few large update queries with case statements replacing the where clauses. This has clawed back some time in a testing scenario.

When we perform the restore over `MonthlyDB`, even though our nightly operations don't touch this database, the same `ReportingDB` procedure has the same symptoms as that of the patching restart. It is the following overnight job after the restore of `MonthlyDB` where the problem procedure is effected. I've trawled the logs for errors and nothing obvious has shown up.

Normal operations ~50-60 minutes - Truncate/insert ~15 minutes, Updates ~45 minutes

Night of most recent restart ~3 hours 15 minutes - Truncate/insert ~1 hour, Updates ~2 hours 10

Last additional restore ~2½ hours - Truncate/insert ~1 hour, Updates ~1½ hours

The restart is the key event, but I'm scratching my head as to why restoring over `MonthlyDB` should impact the `ReportingDB` procedure. I'm planning to run a SQL Server Profiler trace for the overnight period following the restore of `MonthlyDB`, but I'd be grateful for any further guidance/pointers to identify what's going on and for SQL Server to tell me it's having an issue.

Comment: Not really clear what your question is, but have you ever heard the terms cold cache, warm cache?

Comment: A procedure takes a notable dive after a SQL server restart when querying NightlyDB from ReportingDB. MonthlyDB is restored later, same symptoms occur on the same procedure, no restart has taken place, the ReportingDB sp doesn't touch MonthlyDB. I have a restart window between 17-19:00 before the NightlyDB restore starts, any cache warming procedures would be from the NightlyDB database restored the night before? And the cache warming would be just running the problem procedure?

Comment: "A procedure takes a notable dive" in performance or something else?  Perhaps put that clarification as a ONE clear sentence paragraph at the question start before the TLDR; parts

Comment: It sounds like cache, but doesn't explain the slow op when restoring monthly. It could be that disks are "tired", after a big disk operation like a restore, there might be a performance decrease, i have seen it in our system as well, not sure the reason either though. But a question, why not do incremental restores? Oh yeah, it has different versions, so incremental / log shipped restore isn't possible. Did you compare query plan of the key steps between "good" and "bad" runs to see if they're any different?

Comment: Some times I will drop and create a procedure exactly as is, and it will improve performance for awhile.  It might make a better execution plan.  Also if possible improve the performance more even if it is behaving well.  Things will become more clear to you, and issues will be less severe.  I might also recommend inserting or updating in batches if you aren't doing so already.  100,000 records at a time for example can work wonders vs 17 million at once.  For all we know it's a transaction log issue.  Maybe the restore has a small transaction log, and your procedure needs to free up GB for it

Comment: After the restore you will need to update the statistics since you are moving UP a  server version.

Comment: Have you checked if the execution plans are different on different runs?